# Grabbing multiple string inputs from System.in using Scanner

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

My problem is related to grabbing multiple user input strings using `Scanner` on `System.in` to retrieve a username/password tuple and store the tuple in a String array.

similar inquiry: [Reading multiple Scanner inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469882/reading-multiple-scanner-inputs)

However, they don't use try/catch and their code seems to work.

When running my code, I get a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` pointing towards the line : `login[1] = input.nextLine();`

```
public void getPassword() throws Exception {
        /* Create a string array to hold username and password */
        String[] login = {"a", "b"};
        System.out.println("Username:\n");
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            login[0] = input.nextLine();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Password:\n");
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            login[1] = input.nextLine();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("username: " + login[0] + "\npassword: " + login[1]);
    }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Don't create a `Scanner` every time you want to read input. Create it once.

Comment: Should I remove the second try and catch and just put all of it in one block?

Comment: also, use hasNextLine(). that should prevent your exception but the way you're using the scanners is not the proper way.

Comment: I read many things about not using multiple wrappers for input stream. However, I'm new to java and my tutorial always uses this weird try/catch thing when opening a new scanner object. Would it be better to put everything into one block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to catch `NoSuchElementException` if you first use one of the `has*()` methods.

For example, the following code will echo the two inputs to the console.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
}
if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This did it for me. I removed the try/catch block and the "throws Exception" and replaced with similar lines above. I did not understand the use of the hasNextLine() method but I looked up documentation and now it is clear. Thank you!