# read multiple variables with scanner in one line

Tags: java

I am trying to read multiple variables from the console with the scanner in only one line (separated with a blank space).

if I type:

```
int hight = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
int width = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
int depth = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
```

then it displays my numbers (for example 1,2,3) like this:

```
1
2
3
```

but I would want it to display my numbers like that: `1 2 3`

Can someone help me?

Comment: No code here displays anything - please clarify what you mean exactly?

Comment: If you want Int than why you reading first in String and than converting it to int

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java reading multiple ints from a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506429/java-reading-multiple-ints-from-a-single-line)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not clear enough.The examples I gave is how it reads it from the console. My goal is to read those 3 integers from the console in only one line.

Comment: @LisaDuschl Can you refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506429/java-reading-multiple-ints-from-a-single-line) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469882/reading-multiple-scanner-inputs).There are plenty of answers there already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `nextInt` instead of `nextLine`:

```
int hight = reader.nextInt();
int width = reader.nextInt();
int depth = reader.nextInt();
```

Your input can then be like this:

```
1 2 3
```

Note that you have to enter all three numbers before pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, or else your input will look like this again:

```
1
2
3
```

Another way to do this is to use a regex to specify the exact format that you want your input to be in, call `nextLine`, and match the line that the user entered to the regex pattern:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)").matcher(reader.nextLine());
if (matcher.matches()) {
    int height = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    int width = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    int depth = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
} else {
    // input was invalid!
}
```

Comment: Never knew matcher can be used like this.TIL a new use for matcher. +1

Answer (score 0):

To input all 3 values in one line you can use. `. readInt()` three times instead of using `.readNextLine()`. That way you can put your input like this `1 2 3` and after pressing `Enter` on the keyboard (which is by default used to end the input) you get what you were asking for.

If your intention was to get an output in one line instead of multiline one, you should use other version of method printing to the console:

```
System.out.print(height + " " + weight +  " " + depth)
```

`System.out.println()` prints the next line character after its argument, `System.out.print()` doesn't.

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: Later in his question he says about displaying these values, I thought it might be helpful. Ok then, I'm editing my answer and hope you reconsider a downvote.

Comment: Yes my bad, please edit, I'll remove the downvote. Also, can you specifically point out that you're answering the second part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment you can simply read numbers as integers like :

```
Scanner br =new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=br.nextInt();
    int b=br.nextInt();
    int c=br.nextInt();
```

Give input as 1 2 3.

Answer (score 0):

For input in single line in space separated format. You can do that using Scanner and BufferReader in Java.
1. Scanner class

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] integers;
String input = sc.nextLine();
String[] strs= input().split(" ");
for(int i=0;i<strs.length;i++){
  integers[i]=Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
}
```

2. BufferReader Class

```
BufferReader br = new BufferReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int[] integers;
String input = br.readLine();
String[] strs= input().trim().split("\\s+");
for(int i=0;i<strs.length;i++){
  integers[i]=Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
}
```