# trying to save multiple inputs from the same scanner in a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to get multiple integer values from the same scanner inside a while loop. I need to store all the values so I can use them later. However I can only get the last value from the scanner when the while loop finishes.

```
int antalHeltal = Integer.parseInt(Antal);             
int noll = 1;                                          
int heltal = 0;                                        
String tal1 = "";                                      
Scanner tal = new Scanner(System.in);                  
while (noll <= antalHeltal) {                          
     noll += 1;                                        
    heltal += 1;                                       
    System.out.print("ange heltal " + heltal + ": ");  
                                                       
    tal1 = tal.next();                                 
                                                       
        try {                                          
            Integer.parseInt(tal1);                    
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {            
            System.out.println("Ogiltigt värde");      
            noll -= 1;                                 
            heltal -=1;                                
        }
```

My variables are written in Swedish so sorry in advance but I hope someone can help me with this. It would be much appreciated.

Comment: `while(1 <= 0)`!??(this loop will never be entered;)

Comment: Did you check [Reading multiple Scanner inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469882/reading-multiple-scanner-inputs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a List since it can grow dynamically:

```
Scanner tal = new Scanner(System.in);                  

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();   // *** Add this

while (noll <= antalHeltal) {                          
    noll += 1;                                        
    heltal += 1;                                       
    System.out.print("ange heltal " + heltal + ": ");  
                                                   
    tal1 = tal.next();                                 
                                                   
    try {  
        // **********************************
        int num = Integer.parseInt(tal1);                          
        list.add(num);     
        // **********************************
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {            
        System.out.println("Ogiltigt värde");      
        noll -= 1;                                 
        heltal -=1;                                
    }
```

To later access the List:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

or....

```
for (int val : list} {
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Comment: Improve your answer for a couple of things: (1) You can use (and also teach the beginners) `noll++` instead of `noll += 1` and `noll--` instead of `noll -= 1` (2) There is no point in `tal1 = tal.next(); int num = Integer.parseInt(tal1);` when you can simply use `int num = tal.nextInt();`. However, the following does make sense: `tal1 = tal.nextLine(); int num = Integer.parseInt(tal1);`.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. Didn't expect to get such good help this quickly. Greatly appreciated